# Powerbuilder : what does this computed field formatter mean

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a computed field, whose format is specified as follows -

`#,##0.00;[RED](#,##0.00);#`

By format, I meant the format value that we can set from the property of the computed field(in the format tab).

What does this format mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format property can contain up to 4 individual format strings, separated by semicolons. Only one is required. These formats are for numbers:

> Positive-format;negative-format;zero-format;null-format

For other data types (string, date, time...):

> Non-null-format;null-format

I'm assuming it's the semi-colon separated list that's throwing you off. If you need help with the elements of each individual format string, comment back and I'll edit it in, but I suspect you'll find what you need faster in the help file (.HLP). (This topic is in the Users Guide, which should be on your system as a CHM file, in the PowerBuilder program group as "Compiled HTML help file", which actually is another place individual format strings are covered pretty well. It's also available [online from Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.dc00844_1150/html/pbug/BFCCJFHF.htm).)

Good luck,

Terry